# Undo/Redo for send forward & bring backward functionality in canvas with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using fabric.js for creating a customized shoe design. I wanted to add undo & redo functionality into it & I successfully done that from [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/phxqt3wh/3/).

I used below code for pushing canvas state.

```
function changeLayer(direction) {
                    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
                    if (activeObject) {
                        if (direction == 'fore')
                            console.log(canvas.bringForward(activeObject));
                        else
                            console.log(canvas.sendBackwards(activeObject));
                    }
                    pushstate();

                }

function pushstate() {
                    if (replayFlag === false) { // i.e. user modified something..
                        var itemProps = [];
                        for (var i in selectedObject) {
                            itemProps.push({
                                "itemNum": selectedObject[i].itemNum,
                                "left": selectedObject[i].left,
                                "top": selectedObject[i].top,
                                "scaleX": selectedObject[i].scaleX,
                                "scaleY": selectedObject[i].scaleY,
                                "angle": selectedObject[i].angle,
                                "flipX": selectedObject[i].flipX,
                                "flipY": selectedObject[i].flipY,
                                "fill": selectedObject[i].fill,
                                "fontSize": selectedObject[i].fontSize,
                                "fontFamily": selectedObject[i].fontFamily,
                                "textBackgroundColor": selectedObject[i].textBackgroundColor,
                                "fontWeight": selectedObject[i].fontWeight,
                                "fontStyle": selectedObject[i].fontStyle,
                                "textDecoration": selectedObject[i].textDecoration
                            });
                        }

                        // get current object properties 
                        onObjectSelected();

                        undoHist.push({
                            "action": "modify",
                            "itemProps": itemProps
                        });
                        redoHist = [];
                    }
                }
```

When I bring the element forward or backward, undo/redo functionality doesn't work properly.

Comment: I appreciate that you've added your code - but please only post the relevant part. This is a quite big chunk to debug...

Comment: sorry for that , this is my first time on stack overflow!! from next time I will keep that in mind. thank u again

Comment: @JitendraPawar: you can [edit] your post to reduce the size of the HTML. That'll aid people that are trying to help you; as it stands there is far too much HTML to work through.

Comment: I updated the question as u suggested, Thank you!!!
you can get the undo/ redo code from the fiddle link I provided in my question